# nbd in subspace topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm studying topology and struggling with simple statement :

Let $X$ be a topological space and $A \subset X$ with subspace topology. Let $x \in A$ then "Every nbd of $x$ in $A$ is a nbd of $x$ in $X$" $\iff$ "$A$ is a nbd of $x$ in $X$"

I need to know why this statement is true to understand the proof of "A locally compact Hausdorff space is $T_{3}$". I tried to use "for open set $V$ in A(subspace topology) there is open $U$ in X s.t. $V = A \cap U$". But it does not help me to prove the above statement. I cannot think of anything but this. How can I prove this statement?

Answer (score 1):

$\implies$ is obvious since $A$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $A$.

For the converse assume that $A$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$. There exist an open set $V$ in $X$ such that $x \in V \subseteq A$. Let $W$ be any neighborhood of $x$ in $A$. There exists an open set $U$ in $A$ such that $x \in U \subseteq W$. We can write $U=A \cap T$ where $T$ is open in $X$. Now $x \in V\cap T$, $V \cap T$ is open in $X$ and $V \cap T \subseteq W$ (because $V \subseteq A$ and $U \subseteq W$). We have proved that $W$ is a neighborhood of $x$ in $X$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't think of V intersection T.